# Overwriting the ToUnicode Map stream in a PDF

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts, pdf-extraction

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678841/pdf-text-extraction-returns-wrong-characters-due-to-tounicode-map/28694708?noredirect=1#comment107528078_28694708) question, mkl provides a fantastic answer to pnj's predicament. We are unfortunately facing a very similar issue (with a different font called [Lohit - Devanagari](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/lohitdevanagari/Lohit-Devanagari.ttf), but still a Devanagari font) The [**second comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678841/pdf-text-extraction-returns-wrong-characters-due-to-tounicode-map/28694708?noredirect=1#comment45734131_28694708) outlines the non-OCR solution steps beautifully, but I suffer from a huge lacuna in my understanding of PDFs and their structure. As such, it would be great if some direction can be given in terms of the following:

1. *overwrite the ToUnicode map in this PDF using a general purpose PDF library with a low-level object access API for a programming language of your choice*: **What library in Python can I use to do this?**
2. *traversing the PDF object structure, finding the ToUnicode map stream, replacing its content, and saving the result.*: **Is there some example where I can see how exactly this is done for any font out there?**

I hope this isn't too broad. Thank you!